# uilocalnotification programmatically in swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uilocalnotification, ios8, uidatepicker

In my project file, I have two seperate UITableViewCells. One containing a UITextfield and the other containing a UIDatePicker. Both of these cells are placed into a UITableViewController to contain them in a table format. I want a local notification to be sent when the user inputs text and sets a date, but so far I haven't been able to find the right tutorial on this topic using Swift programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create your instance of UILocalNotification: 
`var myNotification = UILocalNotification()` 
Next, give the notification it's text: 
 `myNotification.alertBody = "I am a notification!"` 
 Next, set a `NSDate` for when the notification should fire: 
 `myNotification.fireDate = NSDate()` 
 Finally, add your notification to your app: 
 `UIApplication.sharedApplication.scheduleLocalNotification(myNotification)` 
And you should be all set! It should be noted that your UILocalNotification will only fire if your app is not in the foreground (in other words, you can't be in the app). 
 Hope this helped!

Comment: Yes I have referred to this code before, but I couldn't get it to work. Anyways, I solved the problem! Thanks for the help anyways!!